# Real Security in Python

Tags: python, encryption

I've been looking for a way to use a password in an if statement.  Obviously, `if theRawInput == theCorrectPassword:` is extremely non-secure.  Any ideas?  I've seen other questions with this topic, but they all suggest base64, which is also very non-secure (I cracked my own compiled script's password without using the password).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the attacker has access to your password database, the only way to still hide the password is hashing it. Include a [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) to prevent the attacker from relying on generic hash tables:

```
import hashlib
salt = 'uphi8eiV'
hash = 'a7a2a98cc06f5b2935db5d2866670cc8b48116022e5bc30095b6167ddc2f3f96'
if hashlib.md5.hexdigest(salt + rawInput).hexdigest() == hash:
  print('Correct password')
```

Note that this will still not help against poorly chosen passwords. For these, make sure the attacker has no access to the password database. If you want potential attackers to be able run your program, but not access some piece of data your program manipulates, you'll have to move that piece of data to a remote and secured server program which performs the authentication itself.

Comment: OK, but is there any way to hide the code once it's finished?  I already tried compiling to .pyc, but I can still read most of the script.  I also tried chmod to make it execute-only, but executing relies on reading.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @lucase.62 Your security may not be sound if it depends on the attacker not being able to read your code. What you can do is run a secured server that users can use to execute their programs. On a multi-purpose platform (say, Windows, GNU/Linux, Mac OS X)  without specific configuration (which is a truly *complex* problem), it is not possible to provide an executable that they can't read.